# Can you have multiple ingresses that use the same LoadBalancer?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I don't know if I missed something, but I can't seem to find any posts/doc that is related to my question. Maybe I misunderstand the type `ingress` in kubernetes, but is it possible to define multiple ingresses that use the same LoadBlancer? Having to start one LoadBalancer for every ingress is costly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the benefit of using ingress it helps to avoid creating an external LoadBalancer for each LoadBalancer type service. On many cloud providers some of the [ingress controllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/) will create the corresponding external Load Balancer resource for each ingress resource. But using Nginx Ingress controller you need one loadBalancer to expose the Nginx Ingress controller itself. Then create multiple ingress resource and have multiple backends. All the backends are served by same external Load Balancer.

From the [docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/basic-usage/) of Nginx Ingress

> In this section you can find a common usage scenario where a single
>   load balancer powered by ingress-nginx will route traffic to 2
>   different HTTP backend services based on the host name

Comment: Thank you, your answer is very helpful. Is that documented anywhere how the LoadBalancer is reused?